# Кнопка submit без очищения формы

Tags: html, javascript

Приветствую!

Есть поле ввода и с ней кнопка submit. Хочется, чтобы при нажатии на Enter выполнялись кое-какие действия. Но при этом форма очищается от введенного текста. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Этого избежать очень просто: не нужно очищать форму при нажатии на Enter, совершая кое-какие действия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то это должно помочь: [Действия браузера по умолчанию](http://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action).

> Многие события влекут за собой действие браузера.
>
> Например, клик по ссылке инициирует
> переход на новый URL, нажатие на
> кнопку «отправить» в форме — посылку
> ее на сервер, и т.п.
>
> Если логика работы обработчика требует
> отменить действие браузера — это
> возможно.

Comment: Спасибо, а то я возвращал ноль.
Думал, что это одно и то же, и очень сильно удивлялся.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form onsubmit="myFunc()">
  ...
</form>

<script>
  function myFunc() {
    //trololo....
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Посмотрев ответ выше, я подумал, что правильнее было бы написать 
onsubmit = "return myFunc()"

Answer (score 2):

можно реализовать на jQuery, повесить событие на клик по кнопке, но не сопоставлять этой кнопке действие обычным методом. В скрипте для того, чтобы форма не очищалась в конце по произведению всех действий добавьте `return false;`